# Convert Selenium IDE to Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-ide

When I click a button using Selenium IDE I get 2 results in the "Table" tab:

```
selectFrame  {"id":"3f923370-2dae-80d8-f36f-670e9caa7f7d","containerVersion":"7-GA","webContextPath":"/mmm"}
```

and

```
click  xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[2]
```

How do I turn this into usable code in python? Using **driver.switch_to_frame** and **driver.find_element_by_xpath** ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to first switch to the specific frame and then search for the element in the frame. You can try this:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("3f923370-2dae-80d8-f36f-670e9caa7f7d")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button'][2]").click()
```

I'm not familiar with Selenium IDE but I'm assuming that `3f923370-2dae-80d8-f36f-670e9caa7f7d` is the `id` attribute value of the `frame` tag.